# How to Disable Daily Message in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS [Message of the Day (MOTD)]

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When launching the Ubuntu terminal each day, I receive the following message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

This message appears once daily. To prevent its display, I aim to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the daily message that appears in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, follow these steps:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Use the following command to create the `.hushlogin` file in your home directory:

   ```bash
   touch ~/.hushlogin
   ```

   This command creates an empty file named `.hushlogin` in your home directory, which will prevent the daily message from displaying on login.
3. Once the file is created, restart your system or log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

After completing these steps, the daily message should no longer appear on login.